# How can I dynamically change my sequential variables in a do-while loop? (PHP)

Tags: php, variables

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Loop through variables with common name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4394547/loop-through-variables-with-common-name)

So I have these variables, i.e. $a1, $a2, $a3 and so on..

In a do-while loop, is it possible to call the $aXX variable according to the incremental $i?

```
$a1 = ...
$a2 = ...
...
$i = 1
do {
   ...
   ... echo $a(<--- here I want to change from 1 to 2, 3, etc according to $i-->)
$i++;
} while ( $i < ....)
```

Comment: It's possible, but it seems like you better use an array than variables of the form `$aX`. That's what they are there for.

Comment: in case array doesn't satisfy your preconditions, here you are = `$current = "a$i"; echo $$current;`

Comment: @madfriend: `echo ${'a' . $i};` could be used as well.

Comment: thanks everyone for your answers, I'll check them all tomorrow! sorry if it was a duplicate, I tried searching but to no avail (possibly my tags or the context). just a note here, I never actually learned php or whatever, I just 'had' to work with it (lack of personnel) and as I thought, you guys here would be of faster help than any IT member where I work at... thanks again, tomorrow at work time I'll read carefully each answer! thanks again y'all for the quickest response (for me) ever...

Comment: ok it worked great in either way!! so how is it fair to vote as the correct answer here? by time? i'd vote to every answer, but just wanted to be fair with everyone! thanks again

Answer (score 4):

Use an array:

```
$a[0] = 0;
$a[1] = 1;
$a[2] = 2;
foreach($a as $res){
    echo $res." / ";
}
```

Or, as suggested by some:

```
$a0 = 0;
$a1 = 1;
$a2 = 2;

for($i=0;$i<3;$i++)
   echo ${'a' . $i}." / ";
```

But I would stick with the array.

Answer (score 4):

You can use

```
echo ${"a$i"};
```

But as @FelixKling and @madfriend commented, you should use an array instead.

Answer (score 4):

[Variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) to the rescue!

```
$a1 = ...
//...
$i = 1;
do {
    echo ${'a'.$i};
    $i++;
} while ($i < something);
```