# How to sum values from multiple strings using for loop php?

Tags: php, string, for-loop

How I can easily use for loop php to sum all values from strings below?

`$modules_m_1` result should be: **10**

```
  $g_module_row_active_1 = 1;
  $g_module_row_active_2 = 1;
  $g_module_row_active_3 = 1;
  $g_module_row_active_4 = 1;
  $g_module_row_active_5 = 1;
  $g_module_row_active_6 = 1;
  $g_module_row_active_7 = 1;
  $g_module_row_active_8 = 1;
  $g_module_row_active_9 = 1;
  $g_module_row_active_10 = 1;

  $modules_m_1 = $g_module_row_active_1 + $g_module_row_active_2 + $g_module_row_active_3 + $g_module_row_active_4 + $g_module_row_active_5 + $g_module_row_active_6 + $g_module_row_active_7 + $g_module_row_active_8 + $g_module_row_active_9 + $g_module_row_active_10;
```

Comment: Not flagging it since it's not an *exact* duplicate, but there's some info to help you get started in the answers to [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4394547/1941241). Instead of `echo`'ing the variables, you'll want to add them to a new variable and process the result after the loop.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loop through variables with common name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4394547/loop-through-variables-with-common-name)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could achieve that using **dynamic variables** like so:

```
$g_module_row_active_1 = 1;
$g_module_row_active_2 = 1;
$g_module_row_active_3 = 1;
$g_module_row_active_4 = 1;
$g_module_row_active_5 = 1;
$g_module_row_active_6 = 1;
$g_module_row_active_7 = 1;
$g_module_row_active_8 = 1;
$g_module_row_active_9 = 1;
$g_module_row_active_10 = 1;

$modules_m_1 = 0;

for($i=1;$i<=10;$i++)
{

    $modules_m_1 += ${"g_module_row_active_" . $i};

}

echo $modules_m_1;
```